# couldnt find any file inside /var/html folder

Tags: centos

I installed centos 6 i386 on HP compaq 8100 machine. Its showing nothing inside /var/www/html folder. i tried to locate apache index.html in vicinity folders, but all in vain. I cant access localhost too.

Comment: Did you install apache?

Answer (score 1):

You likely just need to install apache:

```
$ yum install httpd
```

Comment: thanks for prompt reply ... i did installed httpd but its not showing any file inside there.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `httpd` package, start the `httpd` service, and then read the page shown when you open localhost in your browser and follow the instructions.

Comment: thanks. but still its not displaying the apache's welcome page. in fact there's no file inside /var/www/html folder

Comment: The welcome page is not in there.

Comment: thanks.. got the localhost. but cant access it on remote machine. i can ping it with IP from remote machine on LAN but can't access the apache.

Comment: The firewall is a completely different issue.

Comment: y can't i get it accessed from remote machine... earlier i installed 'eprints' for institutional repository, but stalled with same problem. It was working well on local machine, but couldn't get it accessed from remote machine on LAN with same subnet. I disables SElinux too, set httpd to the trusted service. but all in vain.\

Comment: The firewall is a completely different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try look in here
/usr/local/httpd

or

/usr/local/apache2

Good luck.

Comment: Not on CentOS.​

Comment: [root@eprints ~]# cd /usr/local
[root@eprints local]# ls
bin  etc  games  include  lib  libexec  sbin  share  src
[root@eprints local]#

Comment: dnt have apache2 or httpd folder there too

Comment: Execute, ps ax, and try to see in the display if the process httpd is running, if so, try to find for the httpd.conf file, and there you will find the working directory for the main web app.

Comment: DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

Comment: Can you please put the log of the apache server ? this could show us what is not loading properly and what it is not making the server to work.

Comment: @Gerson-O which log ?? access_log or error_log ???

Comment: Please add the error_log.

Comment: Tue Feb 21 11:39:50 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Feb 21 11:39:50 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/html/favicon.ico
[Tue Feb 21 11:39:53 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/html/favicon.ico
[Tue Feb 21 11:39:56 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Feb 21 11:48:27 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/

Comment: ok, this could be permissions, please, make sure that the apache user is the owner of this html folder, then add there an index.html with a "It works" message... and then open it on a browser localhost/index.html

Comment: As a test, try to give 775 permissons to that folder, to the apache user, and see if it works, afterwards, try to reduce the permissions as much as needed in order to not open a security breach.

Comment: your welcome, if you find all info useful and it worked, vote !

Comment: @Gerson-O when i tried to access it from windows 7 machine, its showing the message " "192.168.4.215 is online but server is not responding to connection attempts"